# Losing messages between logstash and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm set up as follows while we're testing out the ESK stack and learning how all this works:

- Client server (CS) running filebeat sends output to logstash running on site aggregator node (AN).
- AN runs logstash with some filters and then forwards to rabbitmq on our Elasticsearch/Kibana node (ESK).
- ESK runs rabbitmq, and logstash pulls messages from rabbitmq before sending output to elasticsearch (without filtering). Kibana is our visualization (obviously) and we're all pretty new with elasticsearch so we're not doing much with it directly.

Here's the problem:

CS generates a message. It definitely gets sent to AN, where logstash filters it and fowrwards it on (after echoing it to logstash.stdout). The logstash instance on ESK also sees it (and writes it to logstash.stdout). I can see the messages in both logstash instances. They match and are appropriately tagged. But they aren't visible in Kibana.

Our configs and a sample message from both logs are all in gist form here: https://gist.github.com/wortmanb/ebd37b8bea278d06ffa058c1513ef940

Where could these messages be going? They're not showing up in Kibana -- if I filter on messages with tags: "puppet", I get basically nothing during timeframes when I know these messages are flowing.

Any debugging suggestions?

Comment: Do you see your logs in the Elasticsearch ? Can you put your hand on a log that was not indexed in the Elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes - the puppetserver log messages aren't getting in there. Well, more to the point, the ones that are getting tagged with "_grokparsefailure" are getting in. The ones I'm successfully parsing aren't. We get the occasional multiline stackdump which fails to parse -- I haven't dealt with those yet. I found these by searching for source: "/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.log" in Kibana.

Comment: Just on your architecture, do you really need rabbitmq? You could just transfer your log directly from the logstash at the aggregator node (AN) to ES at your Elasticsearch/Kibana node (ESK). Or perhaps there are constraints not detailed here that force this architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are parsing the date of the log with the date filter, which, by default, replace the `@timestamp` field, which is used to filter according to the date.

> I get basically nothing during timeframes when I know these messages are flowing.

So the messages are not in the timeframe during which they where flowing, but during the timeframe they were written.

You can see the "_grokparsefailure" logs since their date is not parsed, then the `@timestamp` is the reception date in Logstash.

So you'll to change your timeframe to one including the dates of your logs.

Comment: I've set my timeframe to include those timestamps and still can't see them. I've used a timeframe of "last 2 weeks" and don't see any. I'm not saying you're wrong -- is there a way to dump all my data and basically start over so all my experimentation isn't getting in the way? Fortunately, this is a test environment, so I can wreak havoc with impunity.

Comment: @Bret too bad it does not work,  I was sure it was this problem since I already encountered it and it was pretty similar. I have another idea, in your date filter you are using this pattern `yyyy-dd-mm ...`, I think it should be `yyyy-mm-dd`, looking at this date from your examples : `2016-10-05 15:32:18,038`

Comment: @Bret If it's not that, to delete all your data you can use an ES plugin like kopf and delete all the index. Or you can use curl and do `curl -XDELETE [url to your ES]/_all`. It will delete **all** your data, including any Kibana config. You can delete index by index with `curl -XDELETE [url to your ES]/[index name]`; to retrieve index names, you can use `curl -XGET [url to your ES]/_cat/indices`

Comment: @Bret Last idea : from this dates in you gist : `2016-10-05 15:32:18,038` and `2016-10-05T20:32:18.038Z`, apparently the time was converted from local (UTC -5) to UTC time. So perhaps you could not find your logs in your timeframe because of this conversion.

Comment: You're right -- I did goof in the pattern. I caught that yesterday after posting and got it fixed. In fact, it needs to be yyyy-MM-dd, otherwise you get minutes instead of months!

I'll look at the timezone thing to see if that's involved before purging my data. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I can't explain this, but now it's working. We didn't change anything. I just left it alone overnight and now I can pull these documents out just fine. I'm wondering if ES just took some time to get everything caught up.